# Two components with the same state/functions but different UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components that take the exact same props and share the exact same methods.  But they have different UIs.  How would you recommend keeping this DRY? My first idea:

1. Create a Wrapper component that has the onClick method and props/state.
2. Create two UI components that take in the props/state and then render as they need to, such as:

> ```
> <Wrapper>
>   <UIComponent-1 />
> </Wrapper>
>
> <Wrapper>
>   <UIComponent-2 />
> </Wrapper>
> ```

Is there some better way to do this? I was thinking of making the wrapper an HOC but then the onClick functionality would need to be duplicated (or imported from some common file).

Comment: Could you share a simplified example of the two components? It would help in getting an idea of just how they share their functionality.

Comment: By the way, [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) may be a better place to post this :)

Comment: HOC is what you want.  Successor to mixins: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html @cbr I think in this case it's very specific to React and it's not too "opinionated" for SO, since it has an established method created by the designers for this specific use case.  Also codereview as I understand it is for actual real working code, not stubs and theory.  At best it might go to software engineering?  but it's too React specific.

Answer (score 1):

You could split your component into multiple components. Have one component act as the API/interface, defining the props that can be used and have a `render` prop that will take in the presentational component that you want to render in a certain case

Comment: apologies for the lack of detail though, on my phone

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example implementation of [andy mccullough's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62028336/3982562).

This example creates a component that holds a string that can be reversed by calling the `reverse` function. Both the `value` and the `reverse` function are then provided to the render property. You can then decide how you attach the function to the DOM (if at all) and where and how the value is displayed.

I've also added a default `render` property, but if you don't have a default scenario this can be omitted.

The functions provided to `render` are currently anonymous functions, but if you want to re-use them you can store them in a variable or export them.

```js
const {Fragment, useState} = React;
const {Alert, Button} = ReactBootstrap;

const defaultRender = ({value, reverse}) => <span onClick={reverse}>{value}</span>;

function Reversible({initialValue = "", render: Render = defaultRender}) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  const reverse = () => setValue(value => value.split("").reverse().join(""));
  return <Render value={value} reverse={reverse} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Fragment>
    <Reversible initialValue="default render" />
    <Reversible
      initialValue="custom Alert render"
      render={({value, reverse}) => (
        <Alert variant="primary" onMouseEnter={reverse} onMouseOut={reverse}>
          {value}
        </Alert>
      )}
    />
    <Reversible
      initialValue="custom Button render"
      render={({value, reverse}) => (
        <Button onClick={reverse}>{value}</Button>
      )}
    />
  </Fragment>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a custom hook of the common methods then call the hook inside the function components. Looks like your issue has been specified https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html.

As an example

```js
const useCustomHook = (someArgs) => {
 // perform some effects
 return value;
}

// Then your component
const Component = (props) => {

  const value = useCustomHook(someArgs);

 return <div></div>
}
```

I hope it helps.